# I want to handle multiple windows in Edge-ie mode from Selenium

Tags: c++, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-iedriver

I'm running Edge-ie mode on Selenium

The usage version is as follows

Selenium: 3.141 (java)

IEdriver: 3.150.1

So far, I started Edge-ie mode and was able to operate the first screen
However, when I open another screen, I cannot get the window handle,
Cannot operate

It is commented that this is because IE driver is not supported
(Browser.cpp line number 116 to 121)

```
if (this-> is_edge_chromium_) {
    LOG (TRACE) << "Entering Browser :: NewWindow3 but early exiting due to edge mode";
    // In Edge Chromium, we do not yet support attaching to new windows.
    // Quit early and ignore that event.
    return;
  }
```

I think I need to modify the ieDriver to interact with another screen in Edge-ie mode
And now I think it is necessary to open Edge-ie mode instead of ie in the following places
(BrowserFactory.cpp line number 793 to 805)

```
  if (is_protected_mode) {
    hr = :: CoCreateInstance (CLSID_InternetExplorer,
                            NULL,
                            context,
                            IID_IWebBrowser2,
                            reinterpret_cast <void **> (& browser));
  } else {
    hr = :: CoCreateInstance (CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium,
                            NULL,
                            context,
                            IID_IWebBrowser2,
                            reinterpret_cast <void **> (& browser));
  }
```

How can I start Edge-ie mode at the above location?
Is there any other way to fix the IE driver?
(By Google Translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge IE mode should be driven by IE driver. The situation you mentioned is related to [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8868) on GitHub. The official hasn't fixed it yet so there's no way to handle multiple windows in Edge IE mode from Selenium. I suggest that you can provide feedback about this issue to related product team.